# How to prove a recursive sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need some help with finding the limit of a recursive sequence.

Specifically, 
$a_1 = 3$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{3(1+a_n)}{3+a_n}$, which should approach $3^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

However, I would appreciate any example which demonstrates this concept.

My thought was to try and find the explicit form of the equation and then find the limit of that equation, but I am having trouble finding this equation.

Any hints would be great!

Comment: Observe that $\sqrt3=3(1+\sqrt3)/(3+\sqrt3)$.

Answer (score 2):

You need to investigate first whether $a_{n}$ is convergent or not. One way is by finding out whether it is bounded below/above and monotonically decreasing/increasing respectively (for $n>M$, for some $M$).

If you do have concluded that $a_{n}$ do converge to a value, say $a$. Then you can find $a$ by solving

$$ a = 3\frac{1+a}{3+a}$$

This is because in the long run (for large values of $n$), each sequence value will be *'the same'* and equal to the limit.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence converges to a limit $L$ you can substitute $L$ for all the $a$s.  In this case we have $L=\frac {3(1+L)}{3+L}$ which is a quadratic.  If the sequence converges it will be to one of the roots, one of which is $\sqrt 3$.  To prove convergence it is often handy to define $b_n=a_n-L$, so here $b_n=a_n-\sqrt 3$.  Rewrite the recurrence in terms of $b_n$ and you can justify that $|b_{n+1}| \lt k|b_n|$ for some $k \lt 1$, or prove the sequence is Cauchy, or prove it is monotonically increasing/decreasing and bounded.